# BufferedWriter isn't accepting second input from client?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server and client application. They both use a BufferedWriter-InputStreamReader-InputStream to read information coming from the server, or coming from the client

I have it working so I can use

```
bw.write("command");
```

to execute a command on the server side, and output the information back to the client-side.

However, I am running into trouble doing it twice, for two different commands. Here's the code:

Server-sided code:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String input = br.readLine();

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                if (input.equals("increment")) {
                    bw.write(String.valueOf(totalBets.incrementAndGet()));
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                } else if(input.equals("generate")) {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    bw.write(String.valueOf(rand.nextDouble()*99));
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                }
            }
}
```

Client-sided code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                bw.write("increment" + "\n");
                bw.flush();

                String id = br.readLine();

                bw.write("generate");
                bw.flush();

                String roll = br.readLine();
            }
}
```

The first String `id` gets the output from running the `bw.write("increment")`, but when I try to run `bw.write("generate")`, it freezes when running the line: `String roll = br.readLine();`

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it's because you did not write a newline, br.readLine on server is waiting for the line to end.  Try bw.write("generate\n");

Comment: There's no point in a buffered stream if you flush it after every operation.

Comment: @DBug wow, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: @b1j What would you recommend using instead of Buffered?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `PrintWriter` rather than `BufferedWriter`. Use `BufferedReader` to read without leaving data in the underlying operating system's buffers, so they will be buffered at application level, but for writing you want it to go out as soon as you send one complete 'command'.

With a `PrintWriter` you can also use `println` which should solve your problem.

Comment: I said why. Because he wants the data to go out immediately after one complete command and also it offers `println` which solves the immediate problem he has now which was that he was forgetting to put the newline. He already said it was the current problem.

Comment: You said "use BufferedReader to read without leaving data in the underlying operating system's buffers", which is irrelevant, and something unconnected to anything about "for writing want it to go out as soon as you end one complete 'command'". `PrintWriter` only flushes *lines* if you tell it to, and a 'command' isn't necessarily a line. As `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions that you need to know about, it can't be recommended for use over a network.

Comment: @EJP OMG why are you so pedantic? Typically you use `BufferedReader` to read efficiently. Yes it is 'unconnected' with the specific problem, but the OP was using it. But to write to the socket the way he is a `PrintWriter` is more appropriate. Of course it could still be wrapping around a `BufferedWriter` and still have things going on underneath the hood that might need flushing. But that was not my point. The problem was EVIDENTLY the missing end of line. In this case, if you use a little common sense, which you seem to be missing, a command is a line, so it is convenient to use `println`.

Answer (score -1):

You're losing data, or risking it, by creating multiple BufferedReaders. Use the same one for the life of the socket. Ditto the BufferedWriter.